# Keras model.predict function write on file (instead of memory)

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras

I have a fairly large image dataset and I want to know if there's a way I can make keras model.predict 'dump' results on a file on my disk intead of loading a large numpy array on memory, to avoid out of memory issues.

I know I can split the file in small batches and process each batch separately, but I'm wondering if I can alter keras (or python) behavior to direct the result to file (maybe a pickle object?).

Comment: Ok, just ocurred to me that if my computer cannot hold the resulting numpy array into memory, dumping it to a pickle object is no good, cause I'll not be able to load later.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`np.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save the `ndarray` returned by `model.predict` directly,

```
np.savetxt( 'results.gz' , model.predict( test_images ) )
```

Also, the documentation for `np.savetxt` suggests,

> If the filename ends in .gz, the file is automatically saved in
> compressed gzip format. loadtxt understands gzipped files
> transparently.